# Does the string in the `<?php ?>` is a part of PHP?

Tags: php, string

When I watching a PHP tutorial, the author said "combine PHP code with strings":

[image]

I give the code there:

```
<?php
    $name = "Daniel";
    echo $name." is a handsome boy.";
?>
```

I have a question, does the string in the `<?php ?>` is a part of PHP?

or in other language such as `C`, `Python`, does the string is part of it?

Comment: What you are trying to ask?? Everything wrapped inside `<?php` and `?>` is `php`.

Comment: Those are code written in PHP so its a part of PHP code. You can do same in other languages too. Those string are user defined one, not required codes in PHP. Code says, the value in `$name` is added/concated with the other part ` is a handsome boy.` & is displayed out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @iNullPointer I want to know whether the string belongs to PHP code.

Comment: @qg_java_17137 Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<?php` and `?>` tags tell the server that anything in between those tags is PHP and must be processed as such. If it is not in-between those 2 tags then it is not PHP.

In your code example you are concatenating (adding together) 2 strings and echoing out the result to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

`<?php ?>` - They are a set of tags, ***used to mark the beginning and end of a block of code for PHP***

Everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser which allows PHP files to have mixed content. This allows PHP to be embedded in HTML documents, for example to create templates.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP script starts with `<?php` and ends with `?>`. This indicates the overall block of php script. Everything outside of these tags is not considered as php code. This is generally used to distinguished php tag/block/code in or without the presence of HTML, CSS, and javascript.